# Check if textbox text exists in MySql DB

Tags: c#, mysql

guys im connecting my form with mysql db
and i want to check a textbox text if its exist in Database i wrote a code but still even text exist in DB show me error

this is my code :

```
 MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        i = 0;
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from informat where u_ser = '" + metroTextBox2.Text + "' ";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        i = dt.Rows.Count;
        int userial = metroTextBox2.Text.Length;
        if (userial <= 5 || metroTextBox2.Text != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error");
        }
        else {
        test frm = new test();
        this.Hide();
        frm.Show();
        }
```

Comment: Please provide error code with text and stacktrace

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this and [edit] your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM` instead of `SELECT *`. Also use Parameters in SQL query and `WHERE u_ser= @param`.

Comment: this will always show "error" if you provide text as  `metroTextBox2.Text != null` will be true

Comment: oups thanks everybody i didn't focus on the condition thank you all

Answer (score 0):

The following condition will evaluate to true if the textbox contains inputted text. That's why you always get to see the error message in the dialog.

```
if (userial <= 5 || metroTextBox2.Text != null)
  {
      MessageBox.Show("error");
  }
```

Did you mean to use AND operator in the above condition, please review it.